# using split/join to create a new aws key

Tags: amazon-web-services

Alright, so I have the file transfer part working, but what I'm dealing with is on a huge scale (100s of thousands of potential uploads); so what I'm trying to do is this:

Trigger lambda to move source uploaded object to a new location

Location to be a named key that includes the objects name (in a different bucket)

I have it moving the files from one s3 bucket to another, i just can't figure out how to get it to create a new key in my destination bucket based on the name of the uploaded file.

Example:  uploaded file : grandkids.jpg -> lambda put trigger moves file to /grandkids/grandkids.jpg

Thank you all in advance (It doesn't help that I only know the little bit of nodejs/python due to lambda, I am not an experienced coder at all)

Comment: Hi @ftb3, welcome to the community. I would like to get some clarifications on your question. Where are files uploaded to? Are you creating a new folder for every new file? What have you tried, for example, do you have some existing code you could share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to split the filename and use that as the prefix, like below.

```
fn = 'grandkids.jpg'
folder = fn.split('.')[0]
newkey = folder + '/' + fn
print(newkey)

grandkids/grandkids.jpg
```

But what if you have a filename with more than one '.'? Use rsplit and '1' to only split on the farthest right '.'

```
fn = 'my.awesome.grandkids.jpg'
folder = fn.rsplit('.', 1)[0].replace('.', '_') #personal preference to use underscores in folder names
newkey = folder + '/' + fn
print(newkey)

my_awesome_grandkids/my.awesome.grandkids.jpg
```